# input range set value doesn't update thumb display

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, virtual-dom

I have an input range:

```
<input type="range" value="10" min="0" max="100"></input>
```

I render this with virtual dom and change the value attribute so it becomes:

```
<input type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100"></input>
```

But the thumb display doesn't update.
How can I change the value of input range so it updates the thumb display.

```
function view(newValue) {
  return h('input', { attrs: { value: newValue } });
}
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, we should avoid directly mutating the value attribute from outside React. Can you share the code for the thumb-display you mentioned?

Comment: thumb display I mean the thing that you slide on the page. there is no special code for it.

Comment: I change the value attribute on the virtual dom, not directly manipulating the dom myself @ChristopherNgo

Comment: can u explain how do u update the value ? wat do u mean by update it on thee virtual dom?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to update the `range` input, you have it has to be a controlled component (I mean his value must be and `state`), like this:

```
<input
  type="range"
  value={rangeValue}
  onChange={this.handleRangeChange}
  min="0"
  max="100"
  list="tickmarks"
>
</input>
```

In order to store the value, you have to put it an `onChange` function:

```
 handleRangeChange = e => {
   if (e && e.target && e.target.value) {
     console.log(e.target.value)

     this.setState({ rangeValue: e.target.value });
   }
 }
```

This must, for sure update the thumb of the range input.